# WxPython Panel Refresh

Tags: python, wxpython

<strike>Unfortunately, because its giant and dependent on a lot of other things, I can't post proper code for y'all to test, so sorry in advance</strike>

So the general idea is that I have a panel which displays information from a log (a `dict` called `CRDict`).  This log holds the past revisions and I want the user to be able to select which revision they view.  So I move the entire setup (creating and filling sizers based on what is in `self.CRDict`) into a function called `Display()`.  This function sets up a drop down and binds it to a function `OnRevDrop()` which lets the user select which revision to show.  The function `OnRevDrop()` decides which then assigns `self.CRDict` to be the `dict` which holds the info for the selected revision.

The problem is that it only works once.  The user opens the panel, the current revision displays, the user selects a different revision, the panel refreshes and shows the information from the selected revision, then the user selects another revision, and it breaks giving a `KeyError`.  The error is because calling the `GetValue()` function on the drop down *returns an empty string.* This is the source of my problem, though I do not know how to solve it.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be occurring?

Thanks in advance

---

## Alright, working code!

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel 

rev1 = {"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c"}
rev2 = {"A": "d", "B": "e", "C": "f"}
rev3 = {"A": "g", "B": "h", "C": "i"}

RevHist = {"1":rev1, "2":rev2, "3":rev3}


class TestGui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Hey, a GUI!", size=(400,400)) 
        self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1) 

        self.revsList = sorted(RevHist.keys())
        self.CRDict = rev3 

        self.Display()
        self.revDrop.SetValue("3")


    def Display(self):
        crrev = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Revision:")
        self.revDrop = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, choices=self.revsList, style = wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnRevDrop, self.revDrop)

        hboxRev = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hboxRev.Add((20,20), 1)
        hboxRev.Add(crrev)
        hboxRev.Add((0,0), 1)
        hboxRev.Add(self.revDrop)
        hboxRev.Add((20,20), 1)

        sbox1 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Here's where the information goes")
        sbox1.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.staticbox1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sbox1, wx.VERTICAL)

        infoA = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "A: {}".format(self.CRDict["A"]))
        infoB = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "B: {}".format(self.CRDict["B"]))
        infoC = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "C: {}".format(self.CRDict["C"]))

        self.staticbox1.Add(infoA, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.staticbox1.Add(infoB, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.staticbox1.Add(infoC, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(hboxRev, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)    
        self.vbox.Add(self.staticbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10) 
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()

    def OnRevDrop(self, event):
        rev = self.revDrop.GetValue()
        print rev
        self.CRDict = RevHist[rev]

        self.Display()


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
gui = TestGui()
gui.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would check if "rev" has anything in it. If it does not, then don't try to load the dict.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Well that's the problem, ```rev``` is empty when it shouldn't be.  I can error handle so that it doesn't break the code, but it still won't be working like I want it to

Comment: post some form of functioning example showing the problem ...  otherwise you will be hard pressed to get an answer

Comment: @wnnmaw - do you have an empty item in your combobox? If so, then just return when rev = "". Otherwise you'll need to create a small, runnable example that demonstrates the issue (http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps)

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I added a working test case

Comment: @JoranBeasley I added a working test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that you were creating new GUI elements each time instead of simply updating the original GUI elements

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel 

rev1 = {"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c"}
rev2 = {"A": "d", "B": "e", "C": "f"}
rev3 = {"A": "g", "B": "h", "C": "i"}

RevHist = {"1":rev1, "2":rev2, "3":rev3}


class TestGui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Hey, a GUI!", size=(400,400)) 
        self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1) 

        self.revsList = sorted(RevHist.keys())
        self.CRDict = rev3 

        self.CreateGui()
        self.revDrop.SetValue("3")


    def CreateGui(self):
        crrev = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Revision:")
        self.revDrop = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, choices=self.revsList, style = wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnRevDrop, self.revDrop)

        hboxRev = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hboxRev.Add((20,20), 1)
        hboxRev.Add(crrev)
        hboxRev.Add((0,0), 1)
        hboxRev.Add(self.revDrop)
        hboxRev.Add((20,20), 1)

        sbox1 = wx.StaticBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Here's where the information goes")
        sbox1.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.staticbox1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sbox1, wx.VERTICAL)

        self.infoA = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "A: {0}".format(self.CRDict["A"]))
        self.infoB = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "B: {0}".format(self.CRDict["B"]))
        self.infoC = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "C: {0}".format(self.CRDict["C"]))

        self.staticbox1.Add(self.infoA, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.staticbox1.Add(self.infoB, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.staticbox1.Add(self.infoC, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(hboxRev, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)    
        self.vbox.Add(self.staticbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=10) 
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()
    def UpdateValues(self,valueDict):
        for k,v in valueDict.items():
             if hasattr(self,"info{0}".format(k)):
                  getattr(self,"info{0}".format(k)).SetLabel(v)
    def OnRevDrop(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        rev = self.revDrop.GetValue()
        print rev
        self.CRDict = RevHist[rev]

        self.UpdateValues(self.CRDict )


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
gui = TestGui()
gui.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

although for stuff like this I like to create a mixin

```
class EasyWidgetUpdater:
     widgets = {}
     def SetValue(self,valueDict):
         for k,v in valueDict.items():
             if k in self.widgets:
                   set_widget_value(self.widgets[k],v)
     def GetValue(self):
         result = {}
         for k,widget in self.widgets:
             result[k] = get_widget_value(widget)
         return result
```

you need getters and setters

```
def get_widget_value(widget):
    if isinstance(widget,wx.TextCtrl):
       return widget.GetLabel()
    if hasattr(widget,"GetValue"):
       return widget.GetValue()
    raise Exception,"Unknown Widget {0}".format(widget)

def set_widget_value(widget,value):
    if isinstance(widget,wx.TextCtrl):
       return widget.SetLabel(value)
    if hasattr(widget,"SetValue"):
       return widget.SetValue(value)
    raise Exception,"Unknown Widget {0}".format(widget)
```

then you would be able to do something like

```
class WidgetFrame(wx.Frame,EasyWidgetUpdater):
     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
         sz = wx.BoxSizer()
         sz.Add(self.CreateGUI())
         self.SetSizer(sz)
         self.Layout()
         self.Fit()
      def CreateGUI(self):
         return wx.BoxSizer()

 class TestGui(WidgetFrame):
      def CreateGui(self):
          self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1) 
          self.widgets['revision'] = wx.ComboBox(self,-1,choices=[...])
          self.widgets['infoA'] = wx.Label(self,-1,"asdasd")
          ....
          return self.panel
      def OnRevDrop(self,evt):
          CRDict = RevHist[self.GetValue()['revision']]
          self.SetValue(CRDict)
```